# How to send Email in Laravel using Mailgun?

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I'm trying to send some test emails on my localhost, but I'm getting this error message. I'm not sure what this error is related to:

```
exception: "Swift_TransportException"
file: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/highrjobsadminlte/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php"
line: 457
message: "Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied"
```

At first I had my gmail address in there, I googled the error, it said to click on this link `https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha` to enable account access, but that didn't work. Now I'm trying my hotmail email address and I'm still getting this error.

.env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxb38d58a016fc4f03a4b190ac96bf5080.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=xxx
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=my hotmail email address here
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Highr Jobs Inc. - Support Team"
```

ContactFormController.php:

```
public function submit(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);

        $contact = [];

        $contact['name'] = $request->get('name');
        $contact['email'] = $request->get('email');
        $contact['subject'] = $request->get('subject');
        $contact['msg'] = $request->get('msg');

        // Mail Delivery logic goes here
        Mail::to(config('mail.from.address'))->send(new ContactEmail($contact));

        return response()->json(null, 200);
    }
```

ContactEmail.php:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ContactEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $contact;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct($contact)
    {
        //
        $this->contact = $contact;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            //      ->view('view.name');
            ->to(config('mail.from.address'))
            ->subject('Thank you for contacting our Technical Support Department!')
            ->view('emails.contact');
    }
}
```

Contact.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>


Name: {{ $contact['name'] }} <br>

E-mail: {{ $contact['email'] }} <br><br>

Message: {{ $contact['msg'] }}


{{--<h1>{{$title}}</h1>--}}

{{--<p>{{$content}}</p>--}}

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked to ensure the @domain of the sending email is configured? Are you working on windows server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send email from any domain you want (in this case @gmail.com or @hotmail.com). You can send only from domain you authorized in mailgun.
This is a protection from spammers.